# Finding Constants on a Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential, constants

Question (from my sample exercises in calculus):
Find constants $A, B$ and $C$ such that the function 
$$
y=A\sin x+B\cos x
$$

satisfies the differential equation

$$
y''+y'-2y=\sin x.
$$

I am currently stuck to the part where I already had the first and second degree derivative where

$$
\begin{align}
(1) y''+y'-2y = (-A\sin x-B\cos x)+(A\cos x-B\sin x)-2(A\sin x+B\cos x)\\
       = -A\sin x-B\cos x+A\cos x-B\sin x-2(A\sin x)-2(B\cos x)
\end{align}
$$

$$
(2)y''+y'-2y=\sin x <=> -A\sin x-B\cos x+A\cos x-B\sin x-2A\sin x-2B\cos x=\sin x
$$

I forgot what to do next but I know it a few days ago =( I feel it's that part where you find two equations, I think, that would find the equation for finding A first and then B. I feel that my answer is already on my solution but I don't know where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from $$-A\sin x-B\cos x-A\cos x+B\sin x-2A\sin x-2B\cos x=\sin x,$$ you get $$(1+3A-B)\sin x +(3B+A)\cos x =0.$$ This equality must hold for all $x$. Taking $x=0$ and then $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ you find $1+3A-B =0$ and $3B+A =0$. I guess you can finish now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have finished it =)